# AVD Manager button not working after update (Android Studio) [NOT GREYED OUT]

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

Problem:
Unlike other Similar Questions, in my case the Button is NOT greyed out and IT IS clickable too but nothing happens when I click it, No message, no logs, nothing .... It just doesn't open.
I tried opening just the emulator (from the drop down menu which says (NO DEVICE SELECTED) in the toolbar and it opens but It's frozen or Hanged, It's simply unresponsive.

What I have tried :

1. I tried restarting my PC
2. I tried Uninstalling (It had no Uninstall.exe so I installed Android Studio in other directory and even in that AVD was not working .... then I used it's uninstaller.exe to uninstall the older version, Then I reinstalled Android Studio in previous Directory ... yet didn't work).

What Should I do now? This problem started today itself after updating to the BEE update of Android Studio (25 Jan 2022 release)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update : I fixed it by installing older version of Android Studio,
If anyone else is also having this issue, Roll Back to Artic Fox December Version

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing this. Just got the notification for update to Bumblebee, and I think I am not going for that soon.

Comment: Happy to help friend, Maybe there's issue with AVD and not Android Studio but It's better to stick with older version for now atleast.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to downgrade android studio, you can run a emulator device by terminal.

1. First, Go to emulator folder in the android SDK (for example `/Users/janedoe/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator`), list all devices with the following command:
   `./emulator -list-avds`
2. Then, execute the following command with the name of the device you want to run:
   `./emulator -avd Nexus_6_API_24`

For more info visit the android studio documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline

Comment: I tried that too but it wasn't working either

Comment: What's the error or conflict you got when you tried it ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi after the BEE update the device manager button stopped working with me too, you can use the Search option and type device manager to start it if you don't want to make a downgrade. don't know if there  are fixes ...[enter here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaLMn.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).